# Using React Strict mode with random numbers

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks, strict-mode

I'm trying to create a game of Tic-Tac-Toe with an AI using react. I have a function for my AI that retuns a random row and column to place a piece in. However, when using strict mode the AI takes two turns because the random number gets generated again. From the reading that I've done this indicates that I'm updating my board state incorrectly but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Below is my code for placing the mark on the board.

```
const handlePlacePiece = (row: number, col: number) => {
    let currentPiece = board[row][col];
    if (currentPiece === "-") {
        const newBoard = Array.from(board);
        newBoard[row][col] = currentPlayer; // The current players mark either 'X' or 'O'
        setBoard(newBoard);
        setCurrentPlayer(currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X");
    }
};
```

And here is my initial board state:

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState([
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"],
]);
```

Here is my ai function:

```
export function easyAi(board: any) {
    let col = getRandomMove(); //Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let row = getRandomMove();
    while (board[row][col] !== "-") {
        col = getRandomMove();
        row = getRandomMove(); 
    }
    return { row, col };
}
```

Calling handlePlacePiece (this is also an onClick but this produces the correct outcome):

```
if (gameType === "AI") {
        if (currentPlayer === aiPiece) {
            const { row, col } = easyAi(board);
            handlePlacePiece(row, col);
        }
    }
```

Full file on GitHub: https://github.com/lukeypap/Tic-Tac-Toe-React/blob/master/src/components/Board/index.tsx

Please let me know if you need extra details, Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a useEffect anywhere?

Comment: What is calling `handlePlacePiece`? Is it useEffect?

Comment: also try using the callback version of setState for your setCurrentPlayer

Comment: I've updated so you can see where it's called, thanks guys :) edit: no useEffect is used

Comment: try change this `setCurrentPlayer(currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X");` to this `setCurrentPlayer(current => current === "X" ? "O" : "X");`

Comment: Thank you but after changing this it's still the same issue. So what I can tell is once I remove StrictMode it works as intended because the random numbers are still the the same therefore the board already has a piece placed in the slot but because StrictMode runs state twice the numbers are re-calculated causing 2 moves to be generated.

Comment: `StrictMode` runs everything twice to help you find side effects exactly like yours.  You have to find a way to fix it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. The logic for the "AI" to take its turn is right in the function body as an unintentional side-effect. This means anytime the component is rendered for any reason at all the code it invoked. The `React.StrictMode` runs certain functions twice as a way to help you [detect unexpected side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

   ```
   if (gameType === "AI" && !gameOver) {
     if (checkDraw(board) || checkWinner(board)) {
       console.log("setting game over true");
       setGameOver(true);
     } else if (currentPlayer === aiPiece && !gameOver) {
       const { row, col } = easyAi(board);
       handlePlacePiece(row, col);
     }
   }
   ```

   `React.StricMode`

   > Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

   > - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
   > - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
   > - ***Function component bodies*** <--
   > - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
   > - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`
2. The `handlePlacePiece` callback is mutating the `board` state object. All state, *and nested state*, that is being updated should be shallow copied in order to create new references. The callback only creates a shallow copy of the outer `board` array, but all row arrays are still references to the previous state.

   ```
   const newBoard = Array.from(board);
   newBoard[row][col] = currentPlayer; // <-- mutation!
   setBoard([...newBoard]);
   ```

## Solution

Use a functional state update to update the board state from the previous value, using `Array.prototype.map` to shallow copy the rows and columns that are being updated.

Move the "AI" turn logic into a `useEffect` hook. I suggest moving also the game check into a `useEffect` hook to be called when the `board` state updates.

Suggestions:

```
enum PIECE {
  X = "X",
  O = "O",
  EMPTY = "-",
}

interface props {
  gameType: "AI" | "HUMAN";
  selectedPiece: PIECE;
  startingPlayer: PIECE;
}

const index = ({ gameType, selectedPiece, startingPlayer }: props) => {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(
    Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(PIECE.EMPTY))
  );

  const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(startingPlayer);
  const [aiPiece, setAiPiece] = useState(
    selectedPiece === PIECE.O ? PIECE.X : PIECE.O
  );
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);
  const [checkingMove, setCheckingMove] = useState(false);

  const handlePlacePiece = (row: number, col: number) => {
    let mark = board[row][col];
    if (mark === PIECE.EMPTY) {
      setCheckingMove(true);
      setBoard((board) =>
        board.map((boardRow: PIECE[], i: number) =>
          i === row
            ? boardRow.map((boardCol: PIECE, j: number) =>
                j === col ? currentPlayer : boardCol
              )
            : boardRow
        )
      );
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const isWinner = checkWinner(board); // *
    const isDraw = checkDraw(board);

    if (isWinner || isDraw) {
      if (isWinner) {
        console.log(`Winner is: ${isWinner}`);
      } else if (isDraw) {
        console.log("Draw");
      }
      setGameOver(true);
    } else {
      setCurrentPlayer((current) => (current === PIECE.X ? PIECE.O : PIECE.X));
      setCheckingMove(false);
    }
  }, [board]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      !checkingMove &&
      gameType === "AI" &&
      !gameOver &&
      currentPlayer === aiPiece
    ) {
      const { row, col } = easyAi(board);
      handlePlacePiece(row, col);
    }
  }, [checkingMove, currentPlayer, aiPiece, gameType, gameOver, board]);

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

* Note: The `checkWinner` utility was updated to return the winning piece.

```
export const checkWinner = (board: string[][]) => {
  //Rows
  if (
    board[0][0] == board[0][1] &&
    board[0][1] == board[0][2] &&
    board[0][0] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[0][0];
  }
  if (
    board[1][0] == board[1][1] &&
    board[1][1] == board[1][2] &&
    board[1][0] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[1][0];
  }
  if (
    board[2][0] == board[2][1] &&
    board[2][1] == board[2][2] &&
    board[2][0] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[2][0];
  }
  //Cols
  if (
    board[0][0] == board[1][0] &&
    board[1][0] == board[2][0] &&
    board[0][0] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[0][0];
  }
  if (
    board[0][1] == board[1][1] &&
    board[1][1] == board[2][1] &&
    board[0][1] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[0][1];
  }
  if (
    board[0][2] == board[1][2] &&
    board[1][2] == board[2][2] &&
    board[0][2] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[0][2];
  }
  //Diags
  if (
    board[0][0] == board[1][1] &&
    board[1][1] == board[2][2] &&
    board[0][0] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[0][0];
  }
  if (
    board[0][2] == board[1][1] &&
    board[1][1] == board[2][0] &&
    board[0][2] != "-"
  ) {
    return board[0][2];
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Drew! I was reading a similar reply you had on another thread but I couldn't quite implement it. This has worked like a charm, I need to be more careful with copying arrays in the future and also keep logic that's only supposed to run sometimes out of the main function body.
One small clarification, what is the purpose of the checkingMove variable? I tried to walk through but can't understand what it's purpose is only that if I remove it the AI takes 4 turns haha.
Thanks again big help!

Comment: @lukeyp Ah yeah, sorry, since the `useEffect` hook that handles taking/making the "AI"'s turn has several dependencies this was a necessary state to "block", or gate, the "AI" from taking subsequent/concurrent turns while other state related to the board and whose turn it was were being validated and updated.